In Agda, how can I use Monad and Functor at same time?

module Ang where

open import Effect.Monad.State
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Nat
open import Effect.Functor
open import Effect.Monad
open import Effect.Applicative

import Effect.Monad.Identity.Instances
import Effect.Monad.State.Instances
import Data.Maybe.Instances

open RawFunctor {{...}}
open RawMonad {{...}}

a : State ℕ ℕ
a = do
    return 89

b : Maybe ℕ
b = (λ n → n) <$> (just 3)

c : Maybe ℕ
c = do
    return 4

I want to use Functor and Monad at same time, but it looks like that _<$>_ collides between Monad and Functor.

module Ang where

open import Effect.Monad.State
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Nat
open import Effect.Functor
open import Effect.Monad
open import Effect.Applicative

import Effect.Monad.Identity.Instances
import Effect.Monad.State.Instances
import Data.Maybe.Instances using

open RawFunctor {{...}}
open RawApplicative {{...}} hiding (_<$>_)
open RawMonad {{...}} hiding (_<$>_; _<*>_; pure; return)

-- open RawFunctor rawFunctor

a : State ℕ ℕ
a = do
    return 89

b : Maybe ℕ
b = (λ n → n) <$> (just 3)

c : Maybe ℕ
c = do
    return 4

I tried hiding coliding fields and it works fine but..
module Ang where

open import Effect.Monad.State
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Nat
open import Effect.Functor
open import Effect.Monad
open import Effect.Applicative

import Effect.Monad.Identity.Instances
import Effect.Monad.State.Instances
import Data.Maybe.Instances using (maybeMonad)

open RawFunctor {{...}}
open RawApplicative {{...}} hiding (_<$>_)
open RawMonad {{...}} hiding (_<$>_; _<*>_; pure; return)

-- open RawFunctor rawFunctor

a : State ℕ ℕ
a = do
    return 89

b : Maybe ℕ
b = (λ n → n) <$> (just 3)

c : Maybe ℕ
c = do
    return 4

If I have only Monad instance, functor _<$>_ will not work.
To use functor and monad at same time, should I have Monad -> Applicative, Applicative -> Functor instance and open structures in those weird way? Or there are more convinient way to get it?

You can just open RawMonad since it reëxports stuff from RawFunctor and RawApplicative.

But when I have Functor but not Monad one, and Monad one, I need to use both of RawMonad and RawFunctor.

I don't know what you mean. Your first snippet works fine if you just remove the RawFunctor line.

Sorry for bad example. What I thought was this: There are two objects. First object have Functor implementation but no Monad implementation. Second object have Monad implementation. Then, I need to open RawFunctor and RawMonad to use both of them.
